# How do I create a "fat" js file with rollup using esm?

Tags: ecmascript-6, rollup

I have the following code..

```
// ui.js (generated by rollup
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

    (()=>{
         console.log("Wow it actually works");
         Vue.use(VueRouter);
         const routes = [
             {
                 path: '/',
                 component: Viewport
             }
         ];
         const router = new VueRouter({
             mode: "history",
             routes: routes
         });
         window.app = new Vue({ router });
         window.app.$mount('#jg-app');
    })();

<script src="ui.js" type="module"> </script>
```

The problem is when I run this I get...

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This leads me to believe I need a "fat" js that includes dependencies.

I also want to keep everything in es6 modules and avoid introducing say babel.

Is there a way to do this using rollup?

**Update**

Tried this...

```
import Vue from "./vue";
```

But then I get...

> Error: Could not resolve './vue' from src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is not possible. I instead had to move the import from the ui project to the server project and create a static js file that looked like this...

```
//client
import Vue from "./vue"
let app = new Vue(...);
app.$mount('#jg-app');
```

and import the esm.browser version

```
// server
app.use('/vue', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'));
// template
script(src="/main.js" type="module")
```

Now Vue is working, however, dependencies like Vue-Router appear to not have this es.browser style file.

Answer (score -1):

## This is not a solution, it's a workaround

The below rollup config is not esm, it's just a way to create a bundle with dependencies included.

You get **one** minified browser-compatible JS file.

Here's my working example `rollup.config.js` (you should replace `input: 'src/index.js'` with your web app entry point and `output.file` with a location for the generated bundle):

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import visualizer from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";


const browserPlugins = [
    resolve({browser: true}), // so Rollup can properly resolve cuid
    babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        babelrc: false,
        presets: ['es2015-rollup'],
    }),
    // builtins(),
    commonjs(),
    visualizer(),
    terser(),
]

export default [
    // browser-friendly UMD build
    {
        // external: Object.keys(globals),
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: {
            name: 'thinflux',
            file: './dist/browser/thinflux.min.js',
            format: 'umd'
        },
        plugins: browserPlugins,
    }
];
```

One more thing: express should statically serve the `output.file` path, not your source files

Comment: I need to use esm this uses Babel and umd

Comment: well, my answer is not a solution, it's an alternative